# dplyr 0.3 cannot inner_join data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have the following setup and dplyr(0.3) and data.table(1.9.3) loaded.

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.3 dplyr_0.3       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.3.1      magrittr_1.0.1 parallel_3.1.1 plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.2   
[7] reshape2_1.4   stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1
```

Here are the dataset.  2 data.tables and 2 data.frames.  The two sets have the same contents.

```
DT_1 = data.table(x = rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 3), y = c(1,3,6), v = 1:9)
DT_2 = data.table(V1 = c("b","c"),foo = c(4,2))

DT_1_df = data.frame(x = rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 3), y = c(1,3,6), v = 1:9)
DT_2_df = data.frame(V1 = c("b","c"),foo = c(4,2))
```

### data.table way

When do inner join on two data-tables using the data.table way, we get the following result:

```
setkey(DT_1, x); setkey(DT_2, V1)
DT_1[DT_2]
  x y v foo
1: b 1 4   4
2: b 3 5   4
3: b 6 6   4
4: c 1 7   2
5: c 3 8   2
6: c 6 9   2
```

### dplyr0.3 inner_join on data.tables

It gives error when use inner_join of dplyr on two data-tables:

```
inner_join(DT_1, DT_2, by=("x"="V1"))
Error in setkeyv(x, by$x) : some columns are not in the data.table: V1
```

### dplyr0.3 inner_join on data.frame & data.table

Another error if work a datatable with a dataframe:

```
inner_join(DT_1, DT_2_df, by = c("x" = "V1"))
Error: Data table joins must be on same key
```

### dplyr0.3 inner_join on data.frames

inner_join however works beautifully on dataframes:

```
inner_join(DT_1_df, DT_2_df, by = c("x" = "V1"))
  x y v foo
1 b 1 4   4
2 b 3 5   4
3 b 6 6   4
4 c 1 7   2
5 c 3 8   2
6 c 6 9   2
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Surely the obvious explanation is that this is a bug?

Comment: @hadley: Suspecting it's a bug as well unless it's an intended design which is unlikely. dplyr and data.table are very useful packages. It'd be great if the functions of the packages could work on both dataframes and datatables seamlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### For completeness, posting research result here.

After checking https://github.com/hadley/dplyr , it seems dplyr "join" has limited functions at the moment. To quote: "Currently join variables must be the same in both the left-hand and right-hand sides." The test below seems to confirm this:

```
library(dplyr); library(data.table)
DT_1 = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT_2 = data.table(V1=c("b","c"),foo=c(4,2)) # note the variable name assigned to first column
DT_2b = data.table(x=c("b","c"),foo=c(4,2)) # note the variable name assigned to first column

inner_join(DT_1, DT_2b, by= "x")
Source: local data table [6 x 4]
  x y v foo
1 b 1 4   4
2 b 3 5   4
3 b 6 6   4
4 c 1 7   2
5 c 3 8   2
6 c 6 9   2

inner_join(DT_1, DT_2, by = c("x" = "V1"))
Error: Data table joins must be on same key
```