# Using R, left_join method not accepting data type

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am running a recipe in R that receives an error that looks like:

`> left_join(ann2012full,agglevel)
Joining by: "agglvl_code"
Error in data.table::setkeyv(y, by$x) : x is not a data.table`.

The two variables are ann2012full, a 3 million+ obs. of 15 variables, and agglevel, a 56 obs. of 2 variables, taken from 2 .csv files.

According to other posts, there are others that have problems with dplyr for similar issues, but the framework for the `by` method is not clear to me. Is there anyone who has been able to repeat the `left_join` function as it was prior to the update?

The two vars have an intersection point, and the function appears to acknowledge that by reporting `Joining by: "agglvl_code"` before the error:

```
> intersect(names(ann2012full),names(agglevel))
[1] "agglvl_code"
```

First few lines of variables in question...

```
head(ann2012full)
   area_fips own_code industry_code agglvl_code size_code year qtr disclosure_code annual_avg_estabs_count annual_avg_emplvl
1:     01000        0            10          50         0 2012   A                                  116233           1828248
2:     01000        1            10          51         0 2012   A                                    1252             56031
3:     01000        1           102          52         0 2012   A                                    1252             56031
4:     01000        1          1021          53         0 2012   A                                     599             11734
5:     01000        1          1022          53         0 2012   A                                       2                13
6:     01000        1          1023          53         0 2012   A                                      17               161
   total_annual_wages taxable_annual_wages annual_contributions annual_avg_wkly_wage avg_annual_pay
1:        76768801894          13424728725            419383612                  808          41990
2:         4194319351                    0                    0                 1440          74857
3:         4194319351                    0                    0                 1440          74857
4:          719641114                    0                    0                 1179          61330
5:             436204                    0                    0                  662          34437
6:           12253089                    0                    0                 1468          76343

head(agglevel)
  agglvl_code                                    agglvl_title
1          10                         National, Total Covered
2          11          National, Total -- by ownership sector
3          12      National, by Domain -- by ownership sector
4          13 National, by Supersector -- by ownership sector
5          14   National, NAICS Sector -- by ownership sector
6          15  National, NAICS 3-digit -- by ownership sector
```

What vars in question look like with str()...

```
> str(ann2012)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3556289 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ area_fips              : chr  "01000" "01000" "01000" "01000" ...
 $ own_code               : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ industry_code          : chr  "10" "10" "102" "1021" ...
 $ agglvl_code            : int  50 51 52 53 53 53 53 53 53 53 ...
 $ size_code              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ year                   : int  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
 $ qtr                    : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ disclosure_code        : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ annual_avg_estabs_count: int  116233 1252 1252 599 2 17 46 32 27 4 ...
 $ annual_avg_emplvl      : int  1828248 56031 56031 11734 13 161 1799 6131 903 632 ...
 $ total_annual_wages     :Class 'integer64'  num [1:3556289] 3.79e-313 2.07e-314 2.07e-314 3.56e-315 2.16e-318 ...
 $ taxable_annual_wages   :Class 'integer64'  num [1:3556289] 6.63e-314 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 ...
 $ annual_contributions   :Class 'integer64'  num [1:3556289] 2.07e-315 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 ...
 $ annual_avg_wkly_wage   : int  808 1440 1440 1179 662 1468 1581 1231 370 1716 ...
 $ avg_annual_pay         : int  41990 74857 74857 61330 34437 76343 82237 64031 19257 89240 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> str(agglevel)
'data.frame':   56 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ agglvl_code : int  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 21 ...
 $ agglvl_title: chr  "National, Total Covered" "National, Total -- by ownership sector" "National, by Domain -- by ownership sector" "National, by Supersector -- by ownership sector" ...
```

I have 10 libraries loaded for this recipe; in all there are 28 loaded.

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"             "package:tcltk"          "package:microbenchmark" "package:rbenchmark"     "package:choroplethr"   
 [6] "package:RColorBrewer"   "package:maps"           "package:ggplot2"        "package:stringr"        "package:dplyr"         
[11] "package:plyr"           "package:sqldf"          "package:RSQLite"        "package:DBI"            "package:gsubfn"        
[16] "package:proto"          "package:data.table"     "package:bit64"          "package:bit"            "tools:rstudio"         
[21] "package:stats"          "package:graphics"       "package:grDevices"      "package:utils"          "package:datasets"      
[26] "package:methods"        "Autoloads"              "package:base"
```

*********************************** found work around *******************************

I got to the bottom: I used `merge`, not `left_join`, specifying `by` as more than `NULL`. So, what was...

```
codes <- c('agglevel','industry','ownership','size')
ann2012full <- ann2012
for(i in 1:length(codes)){
  eval(parse(text=paste('ann2012full <- left_join(ann2012full, ',codes[i],')', sep='')))
}
```

now is...

```
codes <- c('agglevel','industry','ownership','size')
ann2012full <- ann2012
for(i in 1:length(codes)){
  barTitle <- intersect(names(ann2012full),names(eval(parse(text=codes[i]))))
  eval(parse(text= paste('ann2012full <- merge(ann2012full, ',codes[i],',by="',barTitle,'")', sep='')))
}
```

However, it appears that `***_join` in the dplyr method has bugs still to be worked out with the latest update. If there are other opinions, I would love to hear them, as it only works with the modified code, `merge`.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of ann2012full and agglevel?  Also, can you show what str() returns as to both of them?  Finally it helps us if you show the "number of libraries" that you have loaded.

Comment: Looks like `dplyr`'s behaviour might have changed in the newer versions.

Comment: It appears to be so: [rstudio](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/10/13/dplyr-0-3-2/) has some details about an improvement as of 10/14/14, but I'm not seeing the connection, and the changes appear optional.

Comment: This comment appears to be linked to a previous question, which I have now decided either cannot currently be solved or provides no new information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073098/dplyr-0-3-cannot-inner-join-data-table

Comment: Don't put that much code into a comment. You can either update your question with new insights or provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're doing the same problem as I am and having the same issue. There are two issues here (at least for me, when I did it).

The first issue is that, if you're following the recipe, one of your sets of data is a data table, and the other is a date frame. So do `as.data.table(code)` to the second set.

The second issue is that on the fields that are being joined, they're integers in one data set and characters in the other set. So that needs to be fixed (just do `as.numeric()`)

edit: this code is what you want, and works fine on my machine (except you need to change 2013 to 2012 to match up with your data).

```
codes <- c('agglevel', 'industry', 'ownership', 'size')
ann2013full <- ann2013
ann2013full$agglvl_code <- as.numeric(ann2013full$agglvl_code)
ann2013full$own_code <- as.numeric(ann2013full$own_code)
ann2013full$size_code <- as.numeric(ann2013full$size_code)
for(code in codes){
  eval(parse(text = paste('ann2013full <- left_join(ann2013full,as.data.table(', code,'))', sep = '')))
}
```